# URL instead of Paypal Form ( Installment Plan)

Tags: html, paypal

I have a Paypal produced code for installment plan and i want to turn it to a signle url for direct linking.

Here's the code :

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">

<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">

<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="SOME VALUE HERE">

<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.mysite.com/thanks.html"/>

<table>

<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="plan"></td></tr>

<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="os0" value ="option_0"></td><td><strong>Beginner -     £137.50 every month for 4 months</strong></td></tr>

<tr><td></td><td>Number of payments 4</td></tr><tr><td></td><td>Start payments At     checkout</td></tr>

<tr><td></td><td>

<table>

<tr><th align="left">Due*</th><th align="right">Amount</th></tr>

<tr><td>At checkout</td><td align="right">£137.50 GBP</td></tr><tr><td>Every 1 month (x     3)</td><td align="right">£137.50 GBP</td></tr><tr><td COLSPAN="2" ALIGN="right">Total     £550.00 GBP</td></tr></table></td></tr>

<tr><td colspan="3"><i>* We calculate payments from the date of checkout.</i></td></tr>    </table>

<table><tr><td align=center><i>Sign up for</i></td></tr><tr><td><input type="image"     src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_installment_plan_LG.gif" border="0"     name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online."></td></tr></table>

<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif"     width="1" height="1">

</form>
```

I have ready the Paypal developer documentation but couldn't find anyhting useful.
Can you please help me out with this ?
Please note that this is for installment plan (recurring payments)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply append them as GET parameters after https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr.
For example, https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=SOME-VALUE-HERE&return=moredatahere&etc=etc

Comment: Actually it is not working that way.
The correct code is this : https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=SOMEVALUEHERE&on0=plan&os0=option_0

Comment: That's what I said; I only didn't provide the full link (see &more=datahere&etc=etc). Glad it's working for you though! :-)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED !!

After several days and multiple emails and calls to Paypal here is the story.

We have a Pricing Table on our WordPress site that only allows for an email link to be inserted. Since we have installment payment option button and did not want to use the tacky old Paypal button.

**Problem:** The issue is that PP was not getting all of the parameters because it set as a link rather than HTML. Please make sure you encode your parameters appropriately to avoid issues with the URL string losing parameters due to unencoded characters.

**SOLUTION:** Basically you need to add the variables as GET parameters to your URL string. So the link would look something like this 
 https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id= insert button value here&on0=&os0=option_0&currency_code=USD

Place your assigned button value ID in the section"insert button value here".

- watch your spacing!!!!

I feel like I solved one the of greatest mysteries of man kind. Enjoy!