# Paypal Installment Plan without button

Tags: paypal

Is there a way to send the installment plan settings to Paypal via API and not a button? I want to offer a few options to select for installments, but having a ton of Paypal buttons for this would be horrible looking and time consuming.

[URL instead of Paypal Form ( Installment Plan)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519017/url-instead-of-paypal-form-installment-plan)

This topic has info on sending the button data direct by URL without the button, but I am looking to avoid manually generating thousands of buttons. Is there button creation by API or some other way?